# I'm stuck with the code hidden behind an unmovable form when I debugging point reach to breakpoint in C#

Tags: c#, .net

i am using windows forms .net framework When debugging a Winforms app I can no longer either minimize or move the form out of the way to view the code when a breakpoint is reached. The result is that I'm stuck with the code hidden behind an unmovable form. how do i resolve this !!! thanks in advance!!!

i dont know how this is happened or changed something in the forms properties.

the image of form when is hit the breakpoint still form remains maximized

reference image

[image: 1]

Comment: Have you heard about `Alt`+`Tab`?

Comment: But now you can answer the age-old question "what if an unstoppable debugger meets an unmovable form?"!

Comment: i have tried ALT + TAB but its didnt work for me, my form remains maximized as before

Comment: Debugging UI is a nightmare if you only have one monitor. At least two monitors is pretty much essential IMO. Do you have no way of attaching another monitor?

Comment: Sorry ALT-TAB was what I meant but that will not bring VS to the front? Is your form set to Always on Top?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not have a multi monitor system otherwise you could start the app in a different monitor.
Have you tried ALT-ESC to switch to the VS Window with your code?

Comment: i have tried but still didn't work !! neither i minimize the form nor close the form. i have edited my question and added a reference image above.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34000140)

Comment: @Alberto the fact that an answer contains a question mark does not make it not an answer. It posts two solutions: "start the app [o]n a different monitor" and "ALT-ESC to switch to the VS Window".